# Spring: Can I abstract my request mappings away to a base class?

Tags: java, spring

My Spring Boot application has a bunch of REST controller classes, all of which perform more or less the same standard CRUD operations on their respective models, just with different endpoint names (one is `/user`, one is `/group`, etc). It makes sense to pack this behaviour away in a base class, perhaps called `Controller`.

Firstly, **is there a base class like this in Spring already, which I've missed?** It seems like handy behaviour that lots of people would need, so I'm surprised I can't find it.

If not, and I need to write it myself, my problem is: what do I do with the request mapping annotations, like `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping`? Their `value` argument has to be constant, so I can't just use the annotations in the superclass and interpolate each endpoint name into them, as in `@GetMapping("/" + endpointName + "/{id}")`. Do I write my request-handling methods *without* the annotations, then wrap and annotate them in each of my 5-6 subclasses, like this?

```
@RestController
public abstract class Controller<T> {

    public ResponseEntity<T> create(T obj) {
        // Creation behaviour
    }

    // Same for retrieve, update, etc

}

...

public class UserController extends Controller<User> {

    @Override
    @PostMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<User> create(@RequestBody User user) {
        return super.create(user);
    }

    // Repeat for other operations

}

// and repeat for all the other subclasses
```

It seems a little redundant; I'd love it if there was a cleaner way.

Comment: A word of caution...  Inheritance based solutions are tricky to maintain in the longer run. Consider having a Generic Request Handler Service to which your controller could route.

Also, you would not want to tie REST controllers for different entities like that. This will come back and bite you when you thing about versioning your rest API for one entity.

Am curious to understand what value this would bring apart from making the controller code less readable.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest abstracting the common functionality out and share via composition NOT inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a generic abstract controller for your CRUD mappings, like :

```
public abstract class AbstractGenericController<E extends yourGenericEntity> {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractGenericController.class);
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<GenericResult<T>> create(@RequestBody String input) {
// your process
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<GenericResult<T>> update(@RequestBody String input) {
// your process
}
```

Then your controller will extend the abstract controller.